# What does it mean if a sequence is indexed beyond its bounds?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, notation

I'm looking at a paper (*[On Base and Turyn Sequences](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1990-1023764-7)* by C. Koukouvinos, S. Kounias and K. Sotirakoglou) that describes an algorithm for finding specific sequences. 
Part of the algorithm involves finding an intermediary sequence $k$ of length $m$, $m < n$, where $n + 1$ is the length of the final sequence, and summing elements $k_1$ and $k_{n+1}$ then checking congruence. The problem is that $k$ is shorter than $n + 1$ (in some cases, much shorter). I don't think it's a typo in the paper ((33) on page 831 if you're curious), and from experimenting I don't think $n+1$ % $m$ is correct. Does anyone know what this means?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I am not sure I am looking at the correct page, but from what I see, $k$ seems to carry a double index everywhere, e.g., $k_{im}$. Added: Is it possible for you to also mention the page number (between 825-837) given in the document?

Comment: It's on page 831 - I've edited my post to add this. The m in the double index indicates which of the intermediary sequences this is - I left it out of my description to simplify things. The n+1 only appears in the first index, so the second index didn't seem important.

Comment: Well, there's no standard meaning to indexing beyond the bound, if that's your question.  It could mean something in this paper, but I presume the author would've indicated it somewhere. I am not brave enough to dig deeper :-)

Comment: That's okay, I don't blame you :-) As far as I can tell, they don't explain it in the paper. I was hoping there was some common convention for this...